# Ubuntu Server not reading /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

So after getting frustrated searching online and only ever coming up with posts about how to change EM1 to ETH0, I have come here to ask this question:

What would cause Ubuntu Server to not load settings as defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

I had issues even getting server to install with an active connection. I unplugged my cable, did an offline installation, and now, even with all the correct parameters set in `/etc/network/interfaces`, it doesn't load the settings. Doing  `ifconfig -a` just shows `em1` as being unprogrammed. I can set the parameters using `ifconfig add`... etc... but for whatever reason `em1` is not loading what I have in the config file.

All I am asking now, is why would `em1` ignore the config file, or just fail to load it?

Comment: This can be caused by a "syntax" error in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Can you add the content of that file to your question?

Comment: Also, there is no LTS version 13.

Comment: Let's see the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: dan08, that is exactly what it was, thanks, albeit I checked this a bit late :)

Answer (score 2):

My focus was to get static networking to work, period, no matter the name.

I found that the `udev` script that creates the `70-persistent-net.rules` was in fact white-listing everything BUT `em1`, so it was not being generated. I white-listed `em*` to resolve that issue.

I then had to use `ifup` to find out that the `/etc/network/interfaces` file had been generated with an extra carriage return on the 2nd line and thus was causing the network device to fail on start (line 2 was supposed to be on the end of line 1 behind the comments).

I tried doing a fresh install, and again the `/etc/network/interfaces` file had an automatic return on it. Removed that and everything functioned correctly after that. Was able to set a static IP and have it start correctly. I changed the name of `em1` to `eth0` after that, but I did resolve my issue by removing that carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change interface name, it's not the `/etc/network/interfaces` you've to change but `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. See [this](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_network_interface_name) for details.

Comment: Changing the name was secondary. I had to white-list em* in the udev to get the 70-persistent-net.rules to even generate to begin with.